# Insert uniqueidentifier value to new table

Tags: sql-server, uniqueidentifier

SQL Server 2008

I have a table with 2 fields among others
TableA
alterid uniqueidentifier
revnum varchar(50)

Another table has the exact fields as the first one
TableB
alterid uniqueidentifier
revnum varchar(50)

I want to check compare the revnum fields. For each record of TableA I check if there is a record in TableB. If it exists and the revnum fields are different I update the TableB.revnum to the TebleA.revnum. If it does not exist then I add the record from TableA to TableB.

Here is the code

```
    BEGIN
    SET @Prod_curs =CURSOR FOR SELECT s.alterid, s.revnum, r.revnum FROM TableA s LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                TableB r ON s.alterid=r.alterid 
                                WHERE s.revnum<>r.revnum OR r.revnum IS NULL

    OPEN @Prod_curs
    FETCH NEXT FROM @Prod_curs INTO @alterid, @srevnum, @rrevnum

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
        BEGIN                           


            IF @rrevnum IS NULL
                BEGIN                                           
                    INSERT INTO TableB (alterid,revnum) VALUES (@alterid,ISNULL(@srevnum,0))

                END
            IF @srevnum<>@rrevnum 
                BEGIN           
                    UPDATE TableB SET revnum=@srevnum WHERE alterid=@alterid    

                END         

            FETCH NEXT FROM @Prod_curs INTO @alterid, @srevnum, @rrevnum        
        END

        CLOSE @Prod_curs;
        DEALLOCATE @Prod_curs;
END
```

My code works fine in a set of about 15000 records except some records where a weird thing happens.

In TableA I have this record
alterid                                                                        revnum
'A770B280-B4DA-4937-9046-B24E60259AB6'         '2-414922-1--1-1-2-51-0'

When it is store in TableB the values are
alterid                                                                        revnum
'BF18A0EB-A684-486B-B053-55BC2969F1E3'         '2-414922-1--1-1-2-51-0'

For some reason the alterid changes and I can't figure out why.

Can someone help

Comment: don't use a cursor; use the MERGE statement...

Answer (score 0):

seems like code is working fine its just select that you are doing after insert/update.
i do have some unclear thing in your post as well.

Does the column "revnum" is primary key or has unique constraint on it in TableB ?

the result you have shown what is the select stmt you use for TableB ?

was it something like "Select top 1 * from TABLEB where revnum=xyz" ?

i ran you logic on dummy data and update/insert is fine. 
check this code. **what i doubt is in TABLEB you already have some "AlterID" with same "rvnum" value that is not present in "TableA"**

***see the below result where instead (3,3) i am also seeing (4,3)***

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @t1 TABLE
    (
        id      INT
        ,VALUE  INT
    )
    INSERT INTO @t1 ( id, VALUE )
    SELECT 1,1 UNION ALL SELECT 2,2 UNION ALL SELECT 3,3

    DECLARE @t2 TABLE
    (
        id      INT
        ,VALUE  INT
    )
    INSERT INTO @t2 ( id, VALUE )
    SELECT 1,1 UNION ALL SELECT 2,2 UNION ALL SELECT 4,3

    DECLARE @Value1 INT,@Value2 INT,@ID INT ,@Prod_curs CURSOR
    SET @Prod_curs =CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT s.id, s.Value, r.value 
    FROM @t1 s LEFT OUTER JOIN
    @t2 r ON s.id=r.ID
    WHERE s.Value<>r.Value OR r.Value IS NULL
    OPEN @Prod_curs
    FETCH NEXT FROM @Prod_curs INTO @ID, @Value1, @Value2
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        IF @Value2 IS NULL
        BEGIN                                           
            INSERT INTO @T2 (ID,Value) VALUES (@ID,ISNULL(@Value1,0))
        END
        IF @Value1<>@Value2
        BEGIN           
            UPDATE @T2 SET Value=@Value2 WHERE ID=@ID
        END
    FETCH NEXT FROM @Prod_curs INTO @ID, @Value1, @Value2
    END
    CLOSE @Prod_curs;
    DEALLOCATE @Prod_curs;

    SELECT  TOP 1 * FROM @t2 WHERE VALUE = 3
```

[image]

Comment: I finally solved it. The revnum field in TableA had null values, so I guess the join went crazy.  Although the MERGE version that Mitch proposed works a lot faster.  Thanks everyone